# How to group data based on a condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get data from a table. The issue is I have to do a group by based on a column with `DATEDIFF` operation.

Here is my table and expected output:

| Issue_id | Status_from | Status_to | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | User2 | 2021-04-21 12:20:41 |
| 2 | User2 | User3 | 2021-05-11 12:20:41 |
| 3 | User3 | User2 | 2021-06-04 12:20:41 |
| 4 | User2 | User4 | 2021-06-14 12:20:41 |

I want to perform a `datediff` operation based on a condition: grouping by status_from

| Status_to | dateddiff |
| --- | --- |
| User2 | date diff should be (2021-04-21 12:20:41 - 2021-05-11 12:20:41) + (2021-06-14 12:20:41 - 2021-06-04 12:20:41) |
| User3 | date diff should be (2021-06-04 12:20:41 - 2021-05-11 12:20:41) |

Is there any way I can achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is `apply`:

```
select t.status_to,
       sum(datediff(second, t.created, t2.created)) as total_seconds
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.status_from = t.status_to and
            t2.created > t.created
      order by t2.created asc
     ) t2
group by t.status_to;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9cc6b9bdb35e4619d731ce5e99c24e6) is a db<>fiddle.